# Extracting from string array Python

Tags: python, json

I have an array in python that has the following elements at index 0,1,2 and I am trying to return the values as an array to html using flask. However I don't need help returning the values to html. I need help grabbing certain things out of the array. For example I have the following in the array

```
[<Hit {'Developer': 'Office Koukan', 'Publisher': 'Shouei', 'ReleaseDate': 'March 18, 1994', 'Title': 'Idea no Hi'}>, 

<Hit {'Developer': 'Jorudan', 'Publisher': 'VAP', 'ReleaseDate': 'November 18, 1994', 'Title': 'Pachinko Hi Hisshouhou'}>, 

<Hit {'Developer': 'Beam Software', 'Publisher': 'Hi Tech Expressions', 'ReleaseDate': 'October 1, 1993', 'Title': 'hunThe Hunt for Red October'}>]
```

Is there a way to grab Developer, Publisher, ReleaseDate, Title as the keys and then the rest of the information in a separate array?

Comment: Python has lists, not arrays.  Are you using an extension package with arrays (e.g. numpy)?  The contents you posted are not a legal Python list; the **<Hit** tag is not part of Python syntax.

Comment: Yes, there are ways to "grab" information from available data.  However, until we know the current data form and the form you want, it's hard for us to help you.  Also, we expect that you have already tried this yourself: post your best attempt along with a problem description.  "Can someone write this code for me?" doesn't get positive responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one commentator said, your "array" is not a valid python list because of "hit" tag. But assuming you have a list of dictionaries and you want to grab keys and rest of data into a separate list you can use defaultdict and append as shown below.

```
# assuming your data is a list of dictionaries
s = [{'Developer': 'Office Koukan', 'Publisher': 'Shouei', 'ReleaseDate': 'March 18, 1994', 'Title': 'Idea no Hi'}, 

{'Developer': 'Jorudan', 'Publisher': 'VAP', 'ReleaseDate': 'November 18, 1994', 'Title': 'Pachinko Hi Hisshouhou'}, 

{'Developer': 'Beam Software', 'Publisher': 'Hi Tech Expressions', 'ReleaseDate': 'October 1, 1993', 'Title': 'hunThe Hunt for Red October'}]

from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for i in s:
    for k,v in i.items():
        d[k].append(v)

# print out the items
for k,v in d.items():
    print('{}: {}').format(k,v)
```

results in:

```
ReleaseDate: ['March 18, 1994', 'November 18, 1994', 'October 1, 1993']
Publisher: ['Shouei', 'VAP', 'Hi Tech Expressions']
Developer: ['Office Koukan', 'Jorudan', 'Beam Software']
Title: ['Idea no Hi', 'Pachinko Hi Hisshouhou', 'hunThe Hunt for Red October']
```